# problems with ng-click and ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a little modal framework in my app..

Heres my controller:

```
function ModalCtrl($scope){
    $scope.openModal = function(name){
        $scope.modalStatus = true;
    }
    $scope.closeModal = function(name){
        $scope.modalStatus = false;
    }
    $scope.modal = function(){
        return $scope.modalStatus;
    }
    $scope.modalStatus = false;
}
```

And heres the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
  <div ng-show="modal()" class="modal_window">
    <h2>The title</h2>
    <span>The content</span>
    <a ng-click="closeModal()">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
    <a ng-click="openModal('xyz')">Open it up</a>
</div>
```

Just totally doesn't work.. couldn't be more confused

Edit: updated with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TeYfY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked your code in detail, but your ngClick is defined *outside* the ngController, so it doesn't have access to the `openModal` function. You would need it inside the controller to access a method on the scope, e.g.:

```html
<div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
  <div ng-show="modal()" class="modal_window">
    <h2>The title</h2>
    <span>The content</span>
    <a ng-click="closeModal()">Close</a>
  </div>

  <a ng-click="openModal('xyz')">Open it up</a>
</div>
```

If there are more problems than this, please feel free to post a Plunker or jsFiddle and update your question I'd be happy to take a closer look and revise my answer.

PS: This code belongs in a directive.

**Update**

The OP mentioned in the comments that he wants to control the modal from another location. This is often accomplished with a service:

```js
module.factory( 'ModalService', function () {
  var is_visible = false;

  return {
    isVisible: function ( value ) {
      if ( angular.isDefined( value ) ) {
        is_visible = value;
      } else {
        return is_visible;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

In the modal directive, one can listen for the state on the service:

```js
$scope.$watch( ModalService.isVisible, function ( status ) {
  $scope.isVisible = status;
});
```

And from a far-off controller, one can change the status on the service:

```js
$scope.openModal = function () {
  ModalService.setVisible( true );
}
```

This is highly contrived and overly-simplified, but it should illustrate the point. In addition to services, one could also use events to accomplish inter-component communication, but in most cases services are more clean.

Comment: The link actually was in the ng-controller in my actual code (just forgot in this example).. updated with jsfiddle though

Comment: @Elliot Actually, my answer still stands. When you use ngController more than once, you are getting *two separate scopes*, so your variable isn't getting changed in the same scope as the modal. Combine them like I have in my answer and it works just fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/yKX8RflMawhb9XxdtdgT?p=preview

Comment: Hmmm, they're located in different parts of my UI though.. Is this why it should be a directive?

Comment: No, the modal should be a directive so it is reusable. For inter-component communication, one usually uses a service. So you would have a modal service that holds state and a directive that watches properties on the service and can respond to them. I'll add some code to my answer in a few...